# Ethers.js converts 0x to address to chain compatible address, then throws "invalid address" error

Tags: ethers.js

I am trying to create a transaction on the XinFin blockchain in the following way:

```
const tx = {
  to: transaction.to,
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther(transaction.amount.toString()).toHexString(),
  nonce: txCount,
};

try {
  await ethersWallet.sendTransaction(tx);
  //...
```

The tx data is as follows:

```
{"to": "0x...", "value": "0x0de0b6b3a7640000","nonce": 0}
```

I double checked and the from and to addresses are correct and not in XDC format as the above data shows.

But I am receiving the following error:

```
[Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="xdc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.7.0)]
```

But nowhere I am using xdc as a prefix. It seems that ethers is converting the address internally from 0x to xdc and then throws the error.

I am using ethers v5.7.2.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

For standard EVM tooling switch your RPC to:

```
Apothem: https://erpc.apothem.network/
Mainnet: https://erpc.xinfin.network/
Mainnet: https://rpc-xdc.icecreamswap.com/
```

I was getting the same issue with a few different XDC RPC's.  These RPC's seem to handle standard EVM addresses correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you can try using the XinFin network ID and provider when creating your ethers wallet

```
const xdcProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://rpc.xinfin.network');

const xdcWallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, xdcProvider);
```

Then, when creating your transaction, you can use the xdc prefix for the addresses:

```
const tx = {
  to: 'xdc' + transaction.to.substring(2),
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther(transaction.amount.toString()).toHexString(),
  nonce: txCount,
};
```

I hope my answer helps.